# Are simple Lie algebras complete?

Tags: lie-algebras, positive-characteristic

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional simple Lie algebra over a field of characteristic $p >0$.
Is $\mathfrak{g}$ complete? 
If not, under what conditions is $\mathfrak{g}$ complete?

A Lie algebra is complete if its center is zero and all its derivations are inner.

Comment: One sufficient condition is that $\dim(\mathfrak{g})<p$, as it ensures that the Killing form is nondegenerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples of simple modular Lie algebras in characteristic $p>2$ having outer derivations are, among others, the Block algebras and Frank algebras, see [Seligman](https://books.google.at/books?id=p7DxCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=simple+modular+Lie+algebras+with+outer+derivation&source=bl&ots=uuqecLKXU9&sig=ACfU3U1N9cfuc6I8aJV3KEfXWJ1KBhqg4Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih-tqfiKPhAhULlYsKHSMSBmY4ChDoATAEegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=simple%20modular%20Lie%20algebras%20with%20outer%20derivation&f=false). Other examples are certain restricted simple modular Lie algebras of Cartan-type, given in the book by Strade and Farnsteiner.

There is a short argument by Zassenhaus, that a Lie algebra with non-degenerate Killing form has only inner derivations, over a field of arbitrary characteristic.

Comment: A short argument of the latter fact (possibly the same) is given in Proposition 4.4 of these lecture notes: http://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/Lie_cours.pdf

Comment: Thank you Dietrich and YCor for your answer and comments. I am trying to figure out how best to proceed. Given the information that I have received (thank you all) I would change my original question. I think that probably means accepting an answer and then trying to formulate a better question. The examples in Dietrich's answer, answers the original question so I will accept it. Although all comments and answers were useful I can't upvote yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. However, simple Lie algebras with non-degenerate Killing forms are always complete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check out what the Killing form is for a small dimensional case of a Lie algebra that I'm interested in.

Comment: @key Which Lie algebra of low dimension are you interested then?